# How to use Google Extension to find div tags of a url

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am creating a chrome extension that will find all the div tags of a specified url. However I have been very confused how to approach this. Should I use a content script, and if so how do I reliably pass the number of tags to my background page? Also, is it possible to just use XMLHttpRequest on my background html page to find the div tags in the url?

Answer (score 1):

If that is your only requirement, finding the div tags from a specified public URL, then you can just do that in the `background.html` page with XHR as you said.

Something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
...
xhr.send(null);
var query = xhr.responseXML.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log('You have found ' + query.length + ' DIV tags!';
```

I did that before to read a bunch of RSS Links, make sure your response type is XML as well to make sure you take advantage of the responseXML from XHR. Or you could just use the `DOMParser` class and do

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
// Maybe you have to play with text/xml
var dom = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/xml") 
var query = dom.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log('You have found ' + query.length + ' DIV tags!';
```

If your content is dynamic, and you want to get the list of DIVs at that *moment*, then you  must use a Content Script and inject just this:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log('You have found ' + query.length + ' DIV tags!';
```

I assume you want that user triggered, so take a look at [Extension Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to see how you can send a message from the extension to the content script so you could trigger this.

Hope that helps you a little!